# Match 2 sets of data and pull back another value in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I have an excel spreadsheet that contains main UPC numbers and a set of sub numbers that correlate to it.

The first column contains the main UPC numbers. In the 2nd column are items that go in the kitchen, the 3rd and 4th columns contains the numbers that belong on the store floor. 5th column are the numbers actually delivered by the suppliers to the kitchen and 6th numbers delivered to the kitchen.

```
UPC Number  Kitchen           Floor         Kitchen Delivery    Floor Delivery
800503034   6744025    5862250      -          6744025             5862250
877389885   6748626    7737406      -          6748626             7737406
800644104   6749799    5862480      -          6749799             5862480
866918159   6744817     -        9345342       6749817             6745322
866430741   6744022     -           -             -                   -
866387876   6744018    5866995      -          6744018             5866995
866441439   6744864     -        9046628       6749864             6746628
866463146   6744851     -        9046616       6749851             6746616
866430137   6748514     -           -             -                   -
888777875   6742243   9046629       -          6742243             6746629
877648961   6745561   7737391       -          6745561             7737391
866909476   6742030     -           -             -                   -
800899755   6744029   5862254       -          6744029                -
800425780   6749999   5862478       -          6749999             5862478
```

What I primarily want to do is find the deliveries that were done correctly. That is where column 2 matches column 5 and either column 3 or 4 match column 6 and then put the main UPC number (column 1) in sheet 2, row A1.

For example, I want in sheet 2, row A1:

```
800503034
877389885   
800644104
```

Eventually, I want to be able to find which number is different and where items weren't delivered but I believe this will give me a good start.

Comment: yes I do. I am open to doing any other formatting to get it in a row

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet11!B2=Sheet11!E2,OR(Sheet11!C2=Sheet11!F2,Sheet11!D2=Sheet11!F2)),Sheet11!A2,"")
```

but your example may be slightly misleading.

Comment: Thank you for that. Unfortunately, that did not work. How can I clarify the example?